# Get value from tuple of tuples in Django template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

In my view I have something like this:

```
KIND_OPS= tuple(enumerate(sorted( ('ter', 'bsdf', 'asd', 'many more strings') )))
```

That will in turn give me this:

```
KIND_OPS= ((0, 'asd'), (1, 'bsdf'), (2, 'many more strings'), (3, 'ter'))
```

Then, in my template I need to know the id of certain value, I'm doing this:

```
{% for k, v in kinds %}{% if v == 'ter' %}{{ k }}{% endif %}{% endfor %}
```

It works but is ugly, there is some other **native** way to solve this? I already did a solution with custon filters and it worked fine too, but I'm looking for a native way...

Answer (score 1):

Turn it into a dictionary:

```
KIND_OPS = {key: index for index, key in enumerate(your_other_list)}
```

And then just do:

```
{{ kinds['ter'] }}
```

Comment: Yes, this could work, but my project is big and for some reason the previous programmer put lots (really), of tuples inside tuples as template context, so I don't want to change all that, at least by now. That's why I'm looking for a way to work with tuples and not dictionaries.

Comment: @GustavoVargas: You're treating tuples of tuples like dictionaries, so you should really be using a dictionary. There isn't a nicer way to abuse tuples.

Comment: I agree with you, but for this solution I'll have to change a lot of views and I can't do this right now.